# friend a template specialization without <>

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

C++03 and C++11 have in the first paragraph of [temp.friend]:

[Edited quote. First try missed a second difference in wording.]

> For a friend function declaration that is not a template declaration:
>
> 1. if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified *template-id*, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template, otherwise
> 2. if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and a matching nontemplate function is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to that function, otherwise,
> 3. [C++03:] if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and a matching specialization of a function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to that function template specialization, otherwise,
>
>    [C++11:] if the name of the friend is a *qualified-id* and and a matching function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to the deduced specialization of that function template, otherwise,
> 4. the name shall be an *unqualified-id* that declares (or redeclares) an ordinary (nontemplate) function.

[The change in wording looks like clarification to me.  Though I guess there might be different ways to interpret the C++03 wording about "finding a specialization in a class or namespace".]

I'm curious about that third bullet.  I wrote this code to try to match its requirements, but both g++ 4.8.1 and clang++ 3.4 reject the code, whether with -std=c++03 or -std=c++11:

```
template <class T> class R;
namespace N {
    template <class T> void test(const R<T>&);
}

template <class T>
class R {
    friend void N::test(const R<T>&);  // 8
    int m;
};

template <class T>
void N::test(const R<T>& rec) { rec.m; }

int main() {
    R<int> r;
    N::test(r);
}
```

Of course if I change line 8 to

```
friend void N::test<>(const R<T>&);
```

the first bullet applies and the program is accepted.  g++ prints a helpful warning saying the friend "declares a non-template function" and suggesting I might want to do exactly that.  The code would probably get more style points for clarity and safety, too.

But shouldn't the code above be covered by the third bullet and valid?  The friend declaration is not a template declaration and uses a *qualified-id* which is not a *template-id* as the name.  And there is no nontemplate function declaration to match for the second bullet.

Is this just a compiler bug common to both?  Or have I misunderstood something, and if so, is there an example of a program that does demonstrate that third bullet?

Comment: +1 Interesting.  I suspect that `<>` is part of the "name of the friend."

Comment: @JohnDibling: *qualified-id* includes among other alternatives *template-id*, so yes, `f<>` is a *qualified-id* altogether.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes, the tokens `<` and `>` are part of the _template-id_.  A _name_ can be an _identifier_, _operator-function-id_, _literal-operator-id_, _conversion-function-id_, or _template-id_ [basic/4].

Comment: @aschepler:  That's your answer then?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Wouldn't `f<>` be an _unqualified-id_ and `::f<>` be a _qualified-id_?

Comment: Same problem, slightly simplified: [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08c88a35e729ecbd)

Comment: @aschepler: Right, missed the `::`, but same thing really, the point is that the `<>` *is* part of the *[un]qualified-id*

Comment: Related: [Issue 674](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#674), which seems to imply the example is well-formed.

Comment: @DyP: Ooh, and the discussion in that issue also seems to imply that the C++03 language could also be interpreted as finding only specializations that were already declared explicitly specialized and/or instantiated.  Which is maybe what the compilers are doing.

Comment: @aschepler No, [I've tested that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/259d11dc3d3719ee).

Comment: .. I just thought what influence does it have that `R` is a class *template*? When [trying with a non-template class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80cd5bf5a71fd9b0) the error message of both compilers suggests this is a name lookup issue.

Answer (score 1):

at line //8,
modified code as :
`friend void N::test< R<T> >( R<T>&);`
**correct too.**

```
friend void N::test<R<T>>(const R<T>&);//one type is friend with one type  #1
friend void N::test<>(const R<T>&);// one type is friend with one type    #2
```

I use some code proof that #1 is equal to #2

At last, I try to answer your question .I am not sure that is right.

```
 friend void N::test(const R<T>&);
```

When instantiating the class R, `R<T>` is a known type . However , the function is

declared as a friend function and really do not instantiate a function template , then the

friend function is a function that does not exist . From the point of view of grammar , the

compiler will prompt you that it is a function rather than a template

```
N::test (r);
```

In this place the function is instantiated, but the compiler does not match with a

friend before the declaration in R class , because you do not declare as a template in R

class, you just declare a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that <> is a condition for the deduction to take place, since from 14.8.2.6,

> In a declaration whose declarator-id refers to a specialization of a function template, template argument deduction is performed to identify the specialization to which the declaration refers. Speciﬁcally, this is done for explicit instantiations (14.7.2), explicit specializations (14.7.3), and certain friend declarations (14.5.4).

In this case, the declarator-id is not a specialization, therefore, no deduction takes place.

Comment: [temp.arg.explicit]/3 says "If all of the template arguments can be deduced, they may all be omitted; in this case, the empty template argument list `<>` itself may also be omitted." A *declarator-id* **is** never a specialization, it's a name. It **refers** to a specialization, see [temp.fct.spec]/1.

Answer (score 0):

N::test is a templated function that takes a class called `T`. It does not take a class called `R<T>`. Change the functions appropriately and it will work.

```
namespace N
{
    template <class T>
    void test ( const T & );
}

template <class T>
class R
{
    friend void N::test ( const R<T> & );
    int m;
};

template <class T>
void N::test ( const T & rec ) { rec.m; }

int main ( )
{
    R<int> r;
    N::test ( r );
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Why does [temp.friend]/3 not apply?

Comment: The deduction works fine e.g. for an explicit instantiation like `template void N::test(const R<int>&);` (in the global namespace; keeping `template<class T> void test(const R<T>&);`).

Comment: Both g++4.9 and clang++3.4 [reject your program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/667de82019cb0932) (even clang++3.6). What compiler did you use? It is also similar to [what I've noticed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/259d11dc3d3719ee) [a year ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459283/friend-a-template-specialization-without#comment28876623_19459283).

Comment: I use MSVC 2013. If we go through the list of requirements:
1) The name of the friend is not templated, so we go to 2.
2) The name of the friend is a qualified-id, but it does not have a matching non-template function (N::test is templated) so we got to 3.
3) The name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching function template is found in the namespace N, so we can use our function.

friend void N::test(const R<T>&); from the original code IS templated (see that T in there?), so it tries to use the first definition with a specialization of a function template, which doesn't exist...

Comment: unless you use the fix OP found.

Specialization of a Function Template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwyxac18.aspx

Member Functions of Templated Classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80dx1bas.aspx

I don't know why my code doesn't work for you, but it looks like OP's fix should.

Comment: Using MSVC is unreliable in determining what is a good behaviour for a compiler wrt name lookup in a template context. For example, it is [known not to use the mandatory 2-phase name lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y86hzch.aspx). -- A template *specialization* is a general term that also refers to implicit instantiations, [temp.spec]/4 "A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either instantiated or explicitly specialized". Note how the MSDN page says "*explicit* specialization".